# How to solve a translation function issue with no arguments and missing a text-domain?

Tags: translation, textdomain

I have a warning via WordPress Themecheck plugin 
WARNING : Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function esc_html__, with the arguments

As you can see, there is no arguments listed above and I'm really lost on this.

Here's the code function:

```
<?php 

    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'matilda_featured_image_nonce' );

    $selected = esc_html__( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'matilda_featured_image', true ) );

?>
```

My text domain is "matilda"

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the right thing to do there is to call `esc_html` instead of `esc_html__`. I have a feeling you don't need any escaping there at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the textdomain to your `esc_html__()` function, do it like this:

```
$selected = esc_html__( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'matilda_featured_image', true ), 'matilda' );
```

So far so good, but this is a complicated matter, as you pass a variable to your translation function.

Be sure to have a limited set of possible data for this field, and have those strings somewhere in your theme. For example, if you have a `<select>` in a metabox, you could do it like that:

```
<select name="matilda_featured_image">
    <option value="<?php _e( 'valueone', 'matilda' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'valueone', 'matilda' ); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php _e( 'valuetwo', 'matilda' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'valuetwo', 'matilda' ); ?></option>
</select>
```

This way you ensure that all the possible values are registered in your translation.

As @MarkKaplun pointed out, you may not need translation in your case whatsoever :)

Comment: I'm sure your method works too but I prefer @MarkKaplun solution. Thanks anyway.